# Push an element to an array if it is not present (no duplicates)

Tags: python, mongodb

I have an event collection which I'm going through to find a category to the specific event and then I'm updating my other collection using a $push statement. The problem is that when two events have the same category it'll create a duplicate, which I don't want.

I know about upserts but I am unsure if they are the best way to go regarding this? And I'm a bit confused when it comes to how to actually write an upsert that works with the "$push"-statement.

This is how my update looks right now:

```
self.users.update({"user_id": event['userid']}, {'$push': {'campaigns': UserCampaign}})
```

..where:

```
UserCampaign = {
        "id": campaign['id'],
        "name": campaign['name']
}
```

The "UserCampaign" gets filled up with the same information from time to time, and since my collection is probably gonna be very huge I want to complete this as efficient as possible.

TLDR; I want to update the array in the document found using a "push" without having the risk of getting duplicates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a better answer to my problem:

By using $addToSet it didn't create duplicates (I also made sure no duplicates where made before by adding all dictionaries to a list):

```
self.users.update({"user_id": event['userid']}, {'$addToSet': {'campaigns': UserCampaigns[i]}})
```

If I just had used $push it would always create duplicate elements in 'campaigns' within the users collection. This happened with and without upsert.

For some reason $each didn't work but wasn't required, I guess PyMongo takes care of that for me.

Comment: ah, I have pointed several others to the $addToSet operator before, but I think the way the question was phrased played into the answers being related to upserts rather than adding to an array of elements, especially when your last summary question explicitly says: "update my collection using a "push"" when you meant something like: update the array in the document using a push without having duplicate elements.  I edited the question to better reflect your actual requirements

Comment: Yes I understand that it might be hard for you guys to know what I need. It was my poor explanation of the problem that was the fault. I am sorry, but I found a working solution and why I specifically pointed out $push in the title were because I really thought that was what I would end up using. Anyway, I read about $addToSet and instantly knew that was the operator which would solve my problem. Thanks for your help and I updated this thread so people as confused as me in the future might stand corrected, as I did.

Answer (score 9):

Send through the third argument on your update as true as per the [MongoDB Docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) and [PyMongo Docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update).

```
self.users.update({"user_id": event['userid']}, {'$push': {'campaigns': UserCampaign}}, True)
```

Comment: I can't find it in the docs, where can I find it? Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: In the docs I linked, just scroll down to the `upserts` portion. I couldn't link directly to it as they use curly braces in the floating URI portion which causes it not to render the link properly.

Comment: I added the link to the PyMongo Docs on `updates()`. The third argument for the function is the `upsert` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Christian has the right arguments in his answer, so I'll leave that part alone (upvoted his answer).

However, you also ask about avoiding duplicates etc.

The key here is to make sure that the criteria part of your update query is specific to the level you want.  An upsert (or an update) is only as good as the criteria you pass into it.  An upsert will insert a new document if it does not find one that matches the criteria, and update will only perform the $push (or whatever update is specified) if the criteria passed in is found (you can multi-update if more than one doc is found too).

In your case, the criteria portion is:

```
UserCampaign = {
        "id": campaign['id'],
        "name": campaign['name']
}
```

Make sure that this part is unique and you will be fine - if this can match more than one document then you are going to have duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but UserCampaign in my example can't be unique.  That's also what I thought. I really don't want it to create a new row in the table. But it will hopefully never be an insert so I guess I'm fine but there is still a small possibility.

Maybe I ought to do some basic python logic before I am updating the  database with the content.

Comment: That might be best - the other option would be to enforce uniqueness for those criteria, but sounds like that is not something you want for other reasons.  You could try adding the duplicate to avoid losing data but marking it as such (an extra field like {dupe : 1}) so you could clean up later

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Why I don't want to enforce uniqueness is because the row that I'm inserting to is gathered before this data is inserted. You can watch it like a user collection then adding some user actions.